# How to change/update login-config.xml without a need to restart jboss server

Tags: jboss, authentication, login-config.xml

I have a Java EE application running on jboss 4.2.3GA.

`Login-config.xml` is including the following piece of code;

```
<authentication>
        ..
        <module-option name="principalsQuery">
            SELECT PASSWORD FROM users WHERE USER_ID=?
        </module-option> 
    </login-module>
</authentication>
```

However, I want to update this SQL with this one

```
select password from users where User_Id=? and Status=1
```

and make it enable WITHOUT restarting JBoss.

I would be glad to hear the solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use DynamicLoginConfig, it is possible by redeploying your application while jboss is still alive; however i have figured out that without DynamicLogin it is almost not possible...